# random_id using HMACkey

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create multiple resources with different suffix. I have two insight resources which i need in same resource group.

I am using HMAC key to create random_id's.
Although it generates them, i am not able to use them in resource function.

The error that i'm getting:
`Because random_id.application_insights_unique_suffix has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances.`

and here i'm getting an error
${random_id.application_insights_unique_suffix.hex}

```
locals {
  hmac_key = "${var.environmentshort}${var.hmac_key}"
}
resource "random_id" "application_insights_unique_suffix" {
  count = "${length(var.application_insights)}"
  keepers = {
    rand = sha256(local.hmac_key)
  }
  byte_length = 4
}
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "appi" {
  for_each            = var.application_insights
  name                = "${var.productname}-${var.environmentshort}-${var.regionshort}-${random_id.application_insights_unique_suffix.hex}"
  location            = var.resourcelocation
  resource_group_name = var.resourcegpname

  application_type                      = each.value["application_type"]
  retention_in_days                     = each.value["retention_in_days"]
  daily_data_cap_in_gb                  = each.value["daily_data_cap_in_gb"]
  tags                                  = merge(var.rgtags,var.ars_tags)
}
```

would be glad if you could help me find an alternate solution.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, by using the `count` meta-argument you have created a **list** of random ids. Should all of those be used?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes, for each resource. Unfortunately count and for statements cannot be used together.  How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the same variable is used in the `random_id` resource and the `azurerm_application_insights` resource, `for_each` can be used in both cases. That will require a small bit of refactoring:

```
locals {
  hmac_key = "${var.environmentshort}${var.hmac_key}"
}
resource "random_id" "application_insights_unique_suffix" {
  for_each = var.application_insights
  keepers  = {
    rand = sha256(local.hmac_key)
  }
  byte_length = 4
}
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "appi" {
  for_each            = var.application_insights
  name                = "${var.productname}-${var.environmentshort}-${var.regionshort}-${random_id.application_insights_unique_suffix[each.key].hex}"
  location            = var.resourcelocation
  resource_group_name = var.resourcegpname

  application_type                      = each.value["application_type"]
  retention_in_days                     = each.value["retention_in_days"]
  daily_data_cap_in_gb                  = each.value["daily_data_cap_in_gb"]
  tags                                  = merge(var.rgtags,var.ars_tags)
}
```

Note that you cannot use `count`[1] and `for_each` [2] meta-arguments interchangeably:

> Note: A given resource or module block cannot use both `count` and `for_each`.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Comment: thank you. I was missing this part.